# Computer won't boot after a new power supply

Tags: boot, power-supply

I recently bought a Rosewill 750-M PSU to replace an Antec Earthwatts 500. My computer worked fine before making the switch. After installing the Rosewill PSU, I attempted to boot. Fans spun up for a second, then turned off. After a second, they spun up again and stayed on. However, I had no video output. I put the old Antec PSU back in, and still had the same problem. I put another GPU in the computer, trying both PSUs, and still nothing. I switched out the monitor also, which didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: You should at least check whether it supplies the correct voltage on 3.3, 5 and 12 V. This is where PSUs usually fail (at least for me).

Comment: is there any sound when the computer start up?

Comment: Only sound I hear is the fans.

Comment: If there's no video, sounds like a bad pin/cable connection. Check the fan and power connectors of the GPU and CPU for bent pins, then try replacing the cables.